# QT - Default ODBC PATH in Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, unixodbc

I have, successfully, installed UNIXODBC and FreeTDS on my Raspberry PI.
I want to use them for connecting to my MS SQL Server Database.

I am sure that this is done properly, since I am able to access my Datbase tables from the command prompt using :
$ tsql -S serverIP -U sql-username -P password

However, I do not know how to use this information in my QT program, so that I can access the information in my QT program.

Please let me know from where does QT get the path of ODBC drivers?  And how to add the path of FreeTDS and UNIXODBC in that path?

Regards,
Ashish